# Updating Chartjs Data with Response from POST Call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, chart.js, react-chartjs

I am currently using react-chartjs-2 to be able to insert a chart into a react component. I am importing the data and options of the chart which are located in another js file. In my app, I am also making a POST call which returns some data in it's body which I want to use as the data for the chart and the chart to be able to update every time a POST request is called. The POST response is currently stored in the state called RESTResponse. So to access the response data outside of the chart in react, I normally call `{this.state.RESTresponse.total}`. I want to be able to use `{this.state.RESTresponse.total}` as the data in my chart. How would I be able to do this? Would it be easier if I didn't use two separate js files for the chart and main component? Thank you!

Here is the code where the chart is being called:

```
import {HorizontalBar} from "react-chartjs-2";
import {Row} from "reactstrap";

// Importing the chart data and options to be used in <HorizontalBar>
import {stackedChart} from "variables/charts.js";

class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      RESTresponse: []
    };
  }  
  async onTodoChange(event){
    let updateJSON = {...this.state.RESTresponse, [event.target.name] : val}
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(updateJSON)
    };
    const response = await fetch('/api/calculate', requestOptions);
    const body = await response.json();
    this.setState({RESTresponse : body });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="content">
          <Row>
            <HorizontalBar
              data={stackedChart.data}
              options={stackedChart.options}
            />
          </Row>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the code where the data and options are defined:

```
let stackedChart = {
  data: canvas => {
    return {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: ' Total Value',
          data: [10], //<--- I want to dynamically update this data value from the POST response
          backgroundColor: '#C4D156'
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        usePointStyle: true,
        borderWidth: 0,
        filter: function(legendItem, chartData) {
          if (legendItem.datasetIndex === 3) {
            return false;
          }
         return true;
         }
      }
    },
    tooltips: {enabled: false},
    hover: {mode: null},
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {stacked: true},
      ],
      xAxes: [{stacked: true,
        ticks: {
             display: false
        }
      },
      ]
    }
  }
};


module.exports = {
  stackedChart
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling "onTodoChange" method ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm calling the onTodoChange method in an input area that I took out to clean up the code. The onTodoChange will fetch the POST response whenever the input form is editted. This is the function that is being called: 

name="a1" value={this.state.RESTresponse.a1} onChange={e => this.onTodoChange(e)}

Answer (score 0):

When `data` is a function, is it invoked with node where the chart is mounted. However you don't seem to be having need for it currently.

Declare data to receive Server response data.

```
  dataFactory: data => {
    return {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: ' Total Value',
          data,
          backgroundColor: '#C4D156'
        }
      ]
    };
  },
```

Then invoke it in render method of your component with data stored in state.

```
<HorizontalBar
  data={stackedChart.dataFactory(this.state.RESTresponse)}
  options={stackedChart.options}
/>
```